# file handling via button click

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I have written this code in an attempt to load a text file into a form but I keep getting an overflow error on the count variable?

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim fdlg As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim count, i As Integer
    count = 0
    fdlg.Title = "Open text file to read"
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    If fdlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fdlg.FileName) = True Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fdlg.FileName)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                count = count + 1 'Overflow Error?
            Loop
            Dim myArray(count) As String
            For i = 0 To i = count
                myArray(i) = objReader.ReadLine()
            Next i
            For i = 0 To count
                TextBox1.Text = myArray(i) & vbNewLine
            Next i
            objReader.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: look up what `Peek()` does

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Plutonix, Peek() reads the next character, but doesn't move the cursor. Thus likely, you're infinite looping there and causing an overflow of the Integer data type. If you're only using the count to size the array, there may be more efficient ways to read the file:

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("")
Dim myStrings As New List(Of String)
While Not objReader.EndOfStream()
   myStrings.Add(objReader.ReadLine())
End While
For Each aString In myStrings
    Textbox1.text &= aString & vbNewLine
Next
```

Or even better, use the string builder, as it is much more efficient, especially if you're trying to add to a text box, adding line by line to the textbox is quite inefficient and can make your app run VERY slow in comparison to using the stringbuilder:

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("")
Dim myStrings As New System.Text.StringBuilder
While Not objReader.EndOfStream()
    myStrings.AppendLine(objReader.ReadLine())
End While
Textbox1.text = myStrings.ToString()
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Peek()'s function I am more familiar with it now. Your reply prompted me to explore the ideas of immutable and mutable variables and I can see the reasoning behind your advice. Unfortunately I am attempting to load a dictionary for a basic spell checker and will need to sort the array with a binary search. Here is my amended code but I still cannot populate the array with the ReadLine() function? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have come up with. My question now is, what kind of smart Split function "Delimiter"'s are there that can be used to insure one word only is stored in an array element? Given that there will be random text file formats: i.e. one word per line, multiple words per line or lines with white space.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim fdlg As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim count, i As Integer
    Dim textLine As String
    count = 0

    fdlg.Title = "Open text file to read"
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"

    If fdlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If System.IO.File.Exists(fdlg.FileName) = True Then

            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fdlg.FileName)

            textLine = objReader.ReadToEnd()
            Dim myArray() As String = Split(textLine, vbCrLf)

            'For i = 0 To myArray.Length - 1
            TextBox1.Text = myArray(6)  'A test to see if myArray is populated
            ' Next i

            objReader.Close()

        Else

            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think that's the rub, a delimiter is expected to be 1 and only on 1 delimiter. Make your life easy and normalize your data. You can use a delimiter and make it easy by using a TextFieldParser: Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fuTheFile.FileContent)
    Dim csvParser As New TextFieldParser(sr)
    csvParser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = True
    While Not csvParser.EndOfData
        Dim fields As String() = csvParser.ReadFields()
        'do something with your array of strings
    End While
End Using